# Properties don't update front-end when written within ICommand-tied function

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, inotifypropertychanged, icommand

UPDATE 3

" I want that the text from this TextBox should be shown in another TextBox(in another view)"

The second textbox in another view is meant to show other information that is tied to the first textbox, but not the copy.

So the user control contains a text box for, say, Bus code. Once I enter bus code, tabbing out will trigger a fetch from the database for other details such as bus name, bus destination, bus model etc.
The others textbox which is in another view then displays the bus name. All following textboxes display destination and so forth. When the command is invoked, and I try to write to the property BusName, it gets assigned (and I call Notify("BusName")) but it does not show on the UI.

Hope that was more clear. Sorry for any confusion caused :).

UPDATE2 - Response to blindmeis

Thanks for your reply though this not appear to be what I was looking for. The tab out is essential because that is how management wants their pages to be populated i.e. when you tab out of a 'code' textbox after entering the code, it will use the code to fetch data from the db to populate the rest of the controls.                                                                                                 This does not appear to have the tab-out behavior in it.                                                                                                                 As for the 3rd dependency property, it is in my original code, I simply did not include it here because the value in the first textbox (user control tabout textbox) is not relevant to the problem.                                Simply, what I am trying to accomplish is that the second textbox must populate when you tab-out of the first textbox.

I could do this with an eventhandler, but wanted to use commands. I am thinking now perhaps commands are not the way to go here and I should switch to using an event handler.

Please advise if you still have any ideas on how to get the second textbox to populate when you tab out of the first (by putting a breakpoint in populate, you will see that the property gets assigned. ).    If I have not understood correctly or missed something here, please let me know. Thanks!

UPDATE! 
I have created a VS2013 solution mimicking my code, which reproduces the problem. It is at this public google drive link as a zip file (takes a few seconds for the download icon to appear):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B89vOvsI7Ubdbk85SVlvT3U2dVU/view?usp=sharing

You will see that the 2nd text box does not update despite the bound property storing the new value.

Greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

---

Original post:

I have a textbox control to which I have tied a key binding based command to go process some actions (in a method that the command has been tied to) when the user hits tab while in the textbox (tabs out).

I have other controls in that page that are boiund to properties in the viewmodel that I write to in that tab-out connected function. When I write my properties in the constructor or somewhere 'outside' that command invokation they seem to work fine and the values show on the page, but when I write them within that command invocation, the properties in the vm contain the values but don't show up on the UI

Any ideas why and how to fix?

Thanks much in advance

From XAML:

```
        <TextBox Name="txtCode" Text="{Binding Path=CodeValue, Mode=TwoWay,      UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Tab"  Command="{Binding RetrieveRecordCmd}" >  </KeyBinding>
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
    </TextBox>
```

From VM:

```
       RetrieveRecordCmd = new GSSCommand(RetrieveRecord, param => this.CanExecuteRetrieveRecordCmd);
```

Command tied function:

```
        public void RetrieveRecord(object obj)
    {
        objPie = null;

        //Check if a record exists for that code
        gssSvcMethodStatusBase = gssSvcClientBase.ReadPies(ref gssSvcGlobalVarsBase, out objPie, out grfaBase, CodeValue);

        if ((objPie != null))  // && (objPie.DateCreated > DateTime.MinValue))
            PopulatePage(objPie);
        else if (objPie == null)            
            InitiateCreateNew();            
        else            
            return;            
    }
```

Comment: Your XAML command binding is to something called 'TextBoxTabOutCmd'. Does this exist somewhere in your ViewModel, or is something else going on between that binding and RetrieveRecordCmd?

Comment: Have you break pointed RetrieveRecord? Does it fire?

Comment: Yes it does, and all the properties get written too

Comment: ..but the UI does not get updated. If you write something to the property in the constructor that shows up on the UI

Comment: Are you raising INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged events for the properties that change?

Comment: your usercontrol is wrong. you have three Properties in your xaml but just 2 Dependency Properties. maybe you could write what you wanna achieve with your Usercontrol. it seems strange to me to use a command to get the value of a textbox...

Comment: second hint, you should NOT set the datacontext to your usercontrol. instead you should use ElementName binding within your bindings

Comment: @blindmeis please see my response, not sure if this notification using "@"  is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the strict sense, but are missing the actual functionality. The interface itself doesn't automatically give you change notifications. You also need to fire the `PropertyChanged` event when each property changes. The standard pattern looks like:

```
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name == value)
                return;
            _name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
```

You should make a habit of writing all mutable properties which you intend to bind to the UI in this format. Snippets can make this easier to do consistently.

Comment: Thanks @John Bowen finally had time to revisit. i had indeed not implemented Notify properly. In this case, it had implemented slightly differently in the ViewModelBase. Thanks for the help, greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

this works, but i dont know if this is the behavior you want.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProblemDemoWPF.TextBoxTabOutUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Name="TabOutTextUserControl"
         >
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Content="UserControl (ucTextBox)->"></Label>
    <TextBox Width="80" Height="30" BorderBrush="Black"
                            BorderThickness="2"                             
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Text="{Binding ElementName=TabOutTextUserControl, Path=CodeValue}">
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

new Dependency Propertie with right binding without DataContext

```
public partial class TextBoxTabOutUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CodeValueProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("CodeValue", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxTabOutUserControl));

    public string CodeValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CodeValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CodeValueProperty, value); }
    }


    public TextBoxTabOutUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Just bind both to LocTextBoxText

```
<Window x:Class="ProblemDemoWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:ProblemDemoWPF"
     Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <loc:TextBoxTabOutUserControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="left" 
                                  CodeValue="{Binding Buscode, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>

    <Label Content="Busname" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Label>
    <TextBox Width="100" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Busname, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>

    <Label Content="Busdestination" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Label>
    <TextBox Width="100" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Busdestination, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>

    <Label Content="Busmodel" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Label>
    <TextBox Width="100" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Busmodel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

add Notify to property setter

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String _buscode;
    private string _busname;
    private string _busdestination;
    private string _busmodel;

    public String Buscode
    {
        get
        {
            return _buscode;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_buscode != value)
            {
                _buscode = value;
                Notify("Buscode");
                FetchData(_buscode);
            }
        }
    }

    private void FetchData(string buscode)
    {
        //DB stuff
        this.Busname = "Name 1234";
        this.Busmodel = "Model 1234";
        this.Busdestination = "Destination 1234";

    }

    public string Busname
    {
        get { return _busname; }
        set { _busname = value; Notify("Busname"); }
    }

    public string Busdestination
    {
        get { return _busdestination; }
        set { _busdestination = value; Notify("Busdestination"); }
    }

    public string Busmodel
    {
        get { return _busmodel; }
        set { _busmodel = value; Notify("Busmodel"); }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply though this not appear to be what I was looking for. The tab out is essential because that is how management wants there pages to be populated i.e. when you tab out of a 'code' textbox after entering the code, it will use the code to populate the rest of the controls. this does not appear to have the tab-out behavior in it.

Comment: please see my response in update to question, it would not fit here

Comment: sorry i dont get what you want :( when i have a UserControl with a TextBox and I want that the text from this TextBox should be shown in another TextBox(in another view)  then i use simply binding like i did in my example. the viewmodel property is bind to the UserControl and to the other TextBox . and when i enter text in the UserControl TextBox then the  text shows up in the other TextBox through the binding with the viewmodel

Comment: Hi @blindmeis oh no no sorry if I conveyed it that way by my description. Let me add to the question the explanation :).

Comment: i think i get it. but i'm at home now :) the question is: should the UserControl trigger the DB or should the viewmodel trigger the DB when the textbox in the Usercontrol changed? if the usercontrol fetch the data from the database --> simply create more DP i bind to it in your view. if the viewmodel fetch the data, you can call this methode simply in your setter.

Comment: Quite understandable if you are not able to get to it until tomorrow but could you elaborate on the second approach - viewmodel fetching data? Specifically, could that be tied to the tab key?

Comment: This appears to be the same problem at first glance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19689447/1556194                                             Although the solution is different than mine I think. I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: i edit my example. if you put a code in the usercontrol the viewmodel fetch the data and show this in your mainview. just cope my code in your example

Comment: Thanks @blindmeis finally had time to revisit. i had indeed not implemented Notify properly. In this case, it had implemented slightly differently in the ViewModelBase. Thanks for the help, greatly appreciate it.